# Stop div from adding on every click

Tags: javascript, toggle

I  have a table with a background image that, when clicked, displays other images for the user to choose from. This is working and appears or hides on click events. However, when the user clicks to add a second image the menu of  images appears again (as it should) but twice. I have commented out a solution I tried. I thought on first click I could display `my_div` and then delete it in `allImages.onclick`. This is throwing up a null error in Chrome, probably understandably. The problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9384957/add-div-on-click-then-toggle-it-on-every-click-after-that) is similar. Hope I added link correctly. Anyway, advice or help appreciated.

```
function addImage(col) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "../www/images/TEST.png";
    col.appendChild(img);
    img.onclick = function () {
        var myImages = new Array();
        myImages[0] = "../www/images/TEST3.png";
        myImages[1] = "../www/images/TEST2.png";
        myImages[2] = "../www/images/TEST4.png";

        for (var i = 0; i < myImages.length; i++) {
            var allImages = new Image();
            allImages.src = myImages[i];

            var newList = document.createElement("ul");
            newList.appendChild(allImages);
            my_div = document.getElementById("showPics");
            my_div.appendChild(newList);
            my_div.style.display = 'block';

            allImages.onclick = function (e) {
                img.src = e.target.src;
                my_div.style.display = 'none';
                //var element = document.getElementById("showPics");
                //element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
            };
        }
    };
};
for (r = 0; r < howOften; r++) {
    row = table.insertRow(-1);
    for (c = 0; c < numDays; c++) {
        col = row.insertCell(-1);
        addImage(col);
    }
}
document.getElementById('holdTable').appendChild(table);
```

Comment: If you run your code through http://jsbeautifier.org/, it appears to have an extra closing `};` before the looping.

Comment: It's part of a larger function so that's probably why. I can add it in if you think it will help.

Comment: Understood. Removed the extra `};` at the end and formatted your code.

Comment: Thanks. Will take more care on formatting.

Comment: So I think the problem is that I am only appending the images to the list and not appending the list to all of the images, or am I slowly going insane? Is this why, if I remove the div on allImages.onclick, I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null? Am I even approaching this the correct way?

Comment: You are creating image list everytime the parent image is clicked.  Move out all the image creation out of img.onclick and remove img.onclick.

Comment: Thanks Jules, I can't try it at the moment, but I think that if I do as you said and move the image list creation and the allImages.onclick function outside and show and hide the div with img.onclick this will work. Will try it later and check back. Thanks.

Comment: I actually tried  that Jules and it didn't work out for me.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code adding ul to hold all img.  It works, but could be better.

```
   function addImage(col) {

        var img = new Image();
        img.src = "../www/images/TEST.png";
        col.appendChild(img);

        var myImages = new Array();
        myImages[0] = "../www/images/TEST1.png";
        myImages[1] = "../www/images/TEST2.png";
        myImages[2] = "../www/images/TEST3.png";

        var container = document.createElement("ul");  //ul to simplify hide/show
        container.style.display = "none";

        for (var i = 0; i < myImages.length; i++) {

            var newList = document.createElement("li");
            var im = document.createElement("img");
            im.src = myImages[i];
            newList.appendChild(im);

            im.onclick = function () {
                img.src = this.src;
            };
            container.appendChild(newList);
        }

        col.appendChild(container);

        col.onclick = function () {
            if (container.style.display == "none")
                container.style.display = "block";
            else
                container.style.display = "none";
        };
    }
```

Comment: Hi Jules. There is a working solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14172370/passing-image-array-values-and-changing-image-source-onclick/14173096#14173096 Thanks for taking the time to help.